# Error installation python MySQLdb OS X 10.12.4

Tags: python, macos, mysql-python

I'm trying to install `mysql-python` module in a `OS X 10.12.4` but I have the following message

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-KAgV3I/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-KAgV3I/mysql-python/
```

I already install `mysql-connector-c` and `Xcode-select --install` and I still have the same error

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version you are looking for...

Comment: I installed with pip, how can know which version that I need ?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue on a clean OS X Sierra environment, and

```
pip install mysql-connector-python==2.1.3
```

worked for me, 2.1.6 seems to have an issue even when Xcode and the mysql-connector-c is installed.